# Custom edit link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code for create edit link custom from front website :

```
<?php
function my_edit_post_link($url,$post->ID,$context) 
{
$url="ddd";
return $url;
}
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link');
?>
```

But give problems , exactly this :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'
```

I don´t know what bad into the function , if you know please tell me something

Thank´s

Comment: You cannot put `$post->ID` in a function definition. You can either pass in the whole `$post` and just use its ID inside your function; or accept an ID, and pass in `$post->ID` when you call the function.

Comment: Expanding on what @andrewsi said, you also wouldn't need to have the $url parameter if you're just going to be setting it inside the function anyway

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
function my_edit_post_link( $url, $post_id, $context )
{

    //...
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'my_edit_post_link', 10, 3 );
```